# Usage of USE_COMPUTED_SIZE in TableColumn

Tags: javafx

Is it possible to use USE_COMPUTED_SIZE for the prefered width of a TableColumn? I have tried but my column then disappear. 
Maybe that it is nonsense?

```
  <TableView id="my-table" fx:id="tagTable" editable="true" stylesheets="@My_Theme.css">
     <columns>
        <TableColumn fx:id="typeColumn" editable="false" maxWidth="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefWidth="-1.0" resizable="false" sortable="false" text="Type" />
        <TableColumn fx:id="contentColumn" editable="false" maxWidth="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefWidth="-1.0" resizable="false" text="CONTENT" />
     </columns>
     <columnResizePolicy>
        <TableView fx:constant="CONSTRAINED_RESIZE_POLICY" />
     </columnResizePolicy>
     <placeholder>
        <Label styleClass="label-dark" text="Nothing to display">
           <padding>
              <Insets bottom="200.0" />
           </padding>
        </Label>
     </placeholder>
  </TableView>
```

Comment: not __C__ .. ;) But what do you want to achieve? Columns are auto-sized on startup, except when they have a width 80.0

Comment: By default the table is empty so I was expecting the column width to be resized to fit to the column titles ("Type" and "Content" in this example).

Comment: should work (btw, I got my last comment the wrong way round: they are autosized if the width - or pref, forgot - is a magic 80, then headers and first n cells are measured and column width set the result)

Answer (score 1):

How I do it, which might not be "the" way you should or want to do it is:

I set all the TableColumns to have the Min and Pref- Width set to USE_COMPUTED_SIZE while the Max Width have the default value of 5000. (I tried setting Max Width to MAX_VALUE but that just ends up with the first column taking up the entire table, and I haven't looked up why that is yet since it works and that it good enough for me :) ).

Also, for the TableView I have the Column Resize Policy set to "constrained-resize" just as you have.

In the image below you can see the results I get, which is 5 evenly sized columns:
[image: Evenly sized columns]

I hope that this might be of some help, and that others may comment if there is a better way or a way in which you can set the Max Width to MAX_VALUE.

Edit: I'm using Java 8 (1.8.181).